# VLC on three projectors has synchronization problems even when all videos are started at the same time via command line

Tags: video, multiple-monitors, vlc-media-player

I have a synchronization problem with VLC on three projectors.

I want to play one video on two side projectors and second one on main projector. Here is my Windows 10 command:

```
"c:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" -f side.mp4 --qt-fullscreen-screennumber=2 --no-one-instance && "c:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" -f side.mp4 --qt-fullscreen-screennumber=1 --no-one-instance && "c:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" -f main.mp4 --qt-fullscreen-screennumber=3 --no-one-instance
```

And generally, it works fine. The VLC instances plays three separate videos on selected projectors.

But the problem is in out of sync between side projectors. Main video may play with one or two seconds latency, but side projectors must be synchronized.

How to get one VLC instance on two side projectors, and the second on main projector?

Answer (score 0):

Several possibilities:

- [VLC Sync](https://github.com/mrkeuz/vlcsync): Utility for synchronize multiple instances of VLC. Supports seek, play and pause.
- See [Synchronized VLC Streaming](http://www.hackedexistence.com/project-vlc.html) that explains using the 'Act as master' preference in Network Synchronization for network clients running VLC for videos that are stored on a common server.